# Weird behaviour of fstream in copying program

Tags: c++, copy, fstream

I modified a source from internet for copying files, so that it can take file paths from user in runtime.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

//C++98 implementation, this function returns true if the copy was successful, false otherwise.

bool copy_file(const char* From, const char* To, std::size_t MaxBufferSize = 1048576)
{
    std::ifstream is(From, std::ios_base::binary);
    std::ofstream os(To, std::ios_base::binary);

    std::pair<char*,std::ptrdiff_t> buffer;
    buffer = std::get_temporary_buffer<char>(MaxBufferSize);

    //Note that exception() == 0 in both file streams,
    //so you will not have a memory leak in case of fail.
    while(is.good() and os)
    {
       is.read(buffer.first, buffer.second);
       os.write(buffer.first, is.gcount());
    }

    std::return_temporary_buffer(buffer.first);

    if(os.fail()) return false;
    if(is.eof()) return true;
    return false;
}



int main()
{
    char fileSourcePath[1000];
    char fileDestinationPath[1000];
    std::cout<<"Enter Path of the source file: ";
    std::cin>>fileSourcePath;
    std::cout<<"Source Path: "<<fileSourcePath<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Enter Destination path: ";
    std::cin>>fileDestinationPath;
    std::cout<<"Destination Path: "<<fileDestinationPath<<std::endl;
   bool CopyResult = copy_file(fileSourcePath, fileDestinationPath);

   std::boolalpha(std::cout);
   std::cout << "Could it copy the file? " << CopyResult << '\n';
}
```

The problem is when I Enter file paths directly in source code at`copy_file(fileSourcePath, fileDestinationPath);` the program works but when I entered paths in runtime the program runs and the terminates giving false result.Also, when i entered c:\upx.exe it gives true status but dosent copies the file.How to fix it?What i am doing wrong.

Comment: what path are you entering?

Comment: I tried with `C:\\upx.exe` and destination as `E:\\upx.exe`, program is working when I entered in source code but not works when entered in runtime. :(

Comment: You should write the file name as `C:\upx.exe` during runtime.

Comment: @timrau I tried it gives true status but when i checked there is no file.

Comment: Immediately after ifstream and ofstream constructors you should test them using operator!.

Comment: @user2672165 what do you mean by test them using operator

Comment: He meant test them using `operator!`. The `!` operator. Basically, "do some error checking".

Comment: No idea if this will help (I'm away from a proper compiler), but you never call `close()` on either stream.